# Are Angular 2 imports for the compiler only?

Tags: angular, ionic2

When making apps using Angular 2 (Ionic 2) I'm not fond of handling all the import statements for every single component I'm going to use, or for every single page I might link to.

Is importing components, and adding them to the constructor, only for the compiler?

In other words, if I include everything, everywhere, for every component, will the bundle size and the performance of the application remain the same?

(Given of course that I import only what the app is actually using, skipping imports that are never used in the application)

Comment: Are you talking about NgModule imports or import {x} from y statements? The former can be simplified a bit with proper use of exports. The latter is a reality of moving to typescript/es6

Comment: I'm talking about import {x} from y. I guess that if this is for typescript, it doesn't impact the compiled app.

Comment: if you're using webpack for bundling, webpack will take care of the imports it will bundle the required dependency only one time even though you have imported it in multiple files.